# Unable to add Pivotal Server in Spring tool suite

Tags: macos, spring-tool-suite, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services, pivotal-tc

I am using **Mac PC** and **"Spring Tool suite"** latest version based on eclipse "4.11.0"
I want to run the project using pivotal server, I am trying to add pivotal server.

Because their is no server added to my project getting error as bellow

**"The specified server is not valid. The .tc-runtime-instance file is missing."**

I have tried but Not working

https://tcserver.docs.pivotal.io/3x/docs-tcserver/topics/install-getting-started.html#homebrew

MacBook Air  OS- MacOS Mojave version-10.14.4

Java jdk version 1.8

Kindly Help me on this

Comment: a.) Make sure you're referencing a tc Server instance that you created, not the root install directory of tc Server, and b.) if the `.tc-runtime-instance` file is missing for some reason, you can just `touch .tc-runtime-instance` and create the file. It should exist in the root of your tc Server instance and an empty file should be sufficient.